# Trying to delete folders that are either empty, or only have hidden files within

Tags: c#, directory-structure, lint

I'm trying to clean up my lightroom folders and have found that sometimes there are hidden files left behind from moving the files from them around.

I did some searching and was able to build this Frankenstein function, but every time it tries to delete an empty folder I get an error saying that the folder is in use by another process....

Basically I am trying to recurs through all of the folders and delete the ones that are empty children, or ones that only have hidden files within. This process should repeat through all of the folders removing their children and eventually the parent if there are no files (or only hidden files) contained therein.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

```
private static void processDirectory(string startLocation)
    {
        //For every folder in this folder, recurse into that folder and take a peek...
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startLocation))
        {
            processDirectory(directory);
            //Get a handle to the directory to get files and whatnot from....
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            //We want to ignore any hidden files in the directory 
            var filtered = files.Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));

            //Make sure there are no other files or directories behind this one
            if (filtered.Count() == 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(directory).Length == 0)
            {
                //Okay it's safe, delete it now.
                di.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: (Caveat: I've not run it to try, so this is just conjecture): does `di` need to be disposed before it'll release the directory?

Comment: Use Process Explorer to find out what process has the directories locked.  Most likely some service of Adobe is still running even if Lightroom isn't running.

Comment: I think it may be related with OS. The file is not totally 'release' yet. not sure whether 'release' is the right word. But we have this issue before. when we try to delete some files that were created in the previous step, it may show this exception. We have to use a loop, delete the file, then check whether file exist, if yes, then wait a short time, 10/100ms, then delete again. We loop 3 times. This seems fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this weren't bizarre enough, this morning when I ran the code it worked just fine!? My folders have been pruned down to only the ones that actually have photos in them, and life is good.
The one thing that I did have to do is add `true` to the `di.Delete()` function. This was because the function was stopping on folders that had hidden files in them.
I am assuming it was something along the lines of what Chris posted above and some latent function was still open from Adobe.

Thanks to everyone that posted a reply!

Cheers!